# Users and Local Groups Report using Powershell?

Tags: windows, security, powershell

Is there a simple way using powershell to show all Local Windows Groups that are active on a machine and the users that are part of those groups? A second part of this question would be if it can be extended to look at more than one machine at a time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact you can with the ADSI type shortcut and the WinNT moniker. Here's an example to list groups and members from your own machine:

```
$server="."
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server,computer"

$computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach {
    write-host $_.name
    write-host "------"
    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    write-host
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the statement $group =[ADSI]$_.Path

Comment: add psbase in front of path (i.e. [ADSI]$_.psbase.Path)

Comment: omg thank you i would have never found this myself ! Is there a way to  know if the members of the localgroup are user or group ? (i want to list members of the localgroup administrators and if a member is a domaingroup list its members )

Comment: I guess you can , try querying the groupType property, it only exist for groups.

Comment: $_.GetType() will fail for 'orphaned' SIDs (unresolved accounts)

Comment: In case of unresolved accounts you get the following error: 

Error while invoking GetType. Could not find member.
+ ...  | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], MissingMemberException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMemberException

Comment: How do I edit this script to output the results to a text or csv file?

Answer (score 7):

Powershell does not have any inherent support for such a feature.  However it's easy to wrap the "net localgroup" command with a couple of powershell functions and thus enable it in the pipeline.

Get Local Groups

```
function Get-LocalGroups() {
  net localgroup | ?{ $_ -match "^\*.*" } | %{ $_.SubString(1) };
}
```

Get Local Group members

```
function Get-LocalGroupMembers() {
  param ([string]$groupName = $(throw "Need a name") )
  $lines = net localgroup $groupName
  $found = $false
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Length; $i++ ) {
    if ( $found ) {
      if ( -not $lines[$i].StartsWith("The command completed")) {
        $lines[$i]
      }
    } elseif ( $lines[$i] -match "^----" ) {
      $found = $true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The loop should break once it hits the line "The command completed", otherwise it will return an empty string as the last element of the array because the last line in the output is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an improved version of Shay Levy's script which works for local groups with "orphaned" accounts which SIDs can't be resolved.

```
$server = "$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server,computer"

$computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach {
    write-host $_.name
    write-host "------"
    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {$_."GetType".Invoke().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    write-host
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jay Levy's answer turned into a function :)

```
Function Get-LocalGroupMembers
{
    Param(
        [string]
        $server = "."
    )
    Try
    {
        $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$( $Server ),computer"
        $computer.psbase.children | 
            where { 
                $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' 
            } |
                ForEach {
                    $GroupName = $_.Name.ToString()
                    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
                    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") |
                        foreach {
                            $memberName = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) -replace "WinNT:", ""

                            $props = @{
                                "LocalGroup" = $GroupName
                                "MemberName" = $memberName
                            }

                            $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
                            Write-Output $obj
                        } # foreach members
                } # foreach group
    }
    Catch
    {
        Throw
    }
}
```

To get the local group members

```
Get-LocalGroupMembers
```

To get the local group members for another machine

```
Get-LocalGroupMembers -Server $Computer
```

Comment: How do I edit this function to output the results to a text or csv file?