# How to get the groups of a local user through powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I am able to get the members of a local group using the following script :

```
$CompStat = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem;
$Localhst = $CompStat.Name;
$Computer = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$localhst+',computer');
$group = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$Localhst+'/groupname,group');
$Members = @($group.psbase.Invoke("Members"));
$Members | ForEach-Object {$MemberNames += $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null);
 Write-Output $MemberNames;
}
```

Similarly how to get the groups of a particular user?

Comment: Are you only interested in local groups?

Comment: Yes..I am interested in local groups only

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of earning me another *necromancer*-badge I'd like to provide some more up to date and more idiomatic code to answer the question.

```bsh
Get-LocalGroup |
    Where-Object { (Get-LocalGroupMember $_).name -eq "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$env:USERNAME" }
```

`$env:USERNAME` can of course be replaced by any other username.

---

Using operators like `-eq` or `-match` with arrays is what makes the not so obvious part in the above  example since they return arrays which - if empty - are an equivalent of `$false` in a boolean context and `$true` otherwise (the operator is applied to each item and the item gets part of the resulting array if the operator returns `$true`):

```bsh
@(1;2;3) -eq 2  # =>  @(2)
@(1;2;3) -eq 4  # =>  @()
@(1;2;3) -ge 2  # =>  @(2;3)
```

Another example of Powershell-*array-magic* that happens here is that a method that is called on an array object that is not a *member* of the array object is called on each item of that object and the return value is an array of the respective return values that are not `$null`. So for example `(Get-LocalGroup).sid.value` returns an array of strings like:

```
S-1-5-32-544
S-1-5-32-545
S-1-5-32-546
...
```

I hope this explains the `(Get-LocalGroupMember $_).name` part in a digestable way.

---

All users and their groups:

```bsh
Get-LocalUser |
    ForEach-Object {
        $nm = $_.name
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $nm
            Groups = Get-LocalGroup |
                Where-Object { (Get-LocalGroupMember $_).name  -contains "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$nm" } |
                ForEach-Object name 
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While writing some automation came up with this piece - getting explicit local groups for given user without traversing all groups available:

```
Get-GroupMembershipLocal([string] $UserName)
{
    $strComputer = $Env:ComputerName
    $User = [ADSI]("WinNT://$strComputer/$UserName,user")

    $Groups = @()
    $User.psbase.Invoke("groups") |foreach `
    {
      $groupname = [string] $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
      $Groups += $groupname
    }
    return ,$Groups
}

$Groups = Get-GroupMembershipLocal "SomeUserName"
Write-Host ($Groups | Out-String)
```

It gets **groups** collection from **user** *SomeUserName* via ADSI WinNT (local), see the line: $User.psbase.Invoke("groups") in the middle. Last two lines provide example of getting & printing out results

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of global groups that a user is a member of you can use "net user username /dom".  I don't know a direct way to display a given user's local group membership, but you could use the script that you already wrote to do it.

For user membership in local groups, I butchered a script found here: [Users and Local Groups Report using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970308/users-and-local-groups-report-using-powershell)

```
 $user = "insert test username"

 $server="."
 $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server,computer"

 $computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach    {
$groupname = $_.name
$group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
$group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | 
foreach {
    $member = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
    if ($member -eq $user)
    {
        write-host $groupname
    }
}
}
```

It is not a good practice to directly put users into local groups.  You should put users into global groups, then global groups into local or domain local groups, and then assign permissions to those local or domain local groups.

See for instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGDLP

Comment: In this one they are getting all the groups and then searching through each member, but is there a better way to get the groups of a user?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The script I posted will, for a user that you specify, find all local groups that that user is a member of on the system.  I thought that was what you were asking for.

Comment: I tried this one. But this was also throwing error.But I was searching for an efficient way to get the groups of user.

Comment: What user are you using as input?  You have to modify the first variable and run it on the server you're interested in.  It worked for me on a Windows 2008 R2 server with both a domain user and a local user.