# How to export list of group and users to CSV?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to export all of the email addresses from my Local Windows Groups and Users that are active to a CSV file.  How do I do this?  I am new to Powershell, but I would like to write a PowerShell script to do this.  I began by importing the activedirectory module and was able to execute some scripts.
Here is a link that does almost everything except this writes the output to the console instead of CSV.  And it freezes and doesn't return to the command prompt after running:
[groups and users to console solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970308/users-and-local-groups-report-using-powershell)

So in this CSV, I'd like to see each group header followed by its member email addresses.

Comment: Can you use a programming language rather than powershell?

Comment: I only linked one duplicate, but there are **many others** (I think > 50% of PowerShell questions here are asking about how to export some such thing to CSV; a good portion of those deal with AD objects). I appreciate that you're new to the language and maybe you've put some effort in and tried some stuff, but you didn't share any of that in the question.

Comment: I spent all day at work trying out different solutions but none of them successfully exported to CSV.  The only ones that worked exported to the console.  I will try the solutions from the duplicate question above on Monday.  Thanks!

Comment: And yes, I could use a programming language but PowerShell seems easiest to me.

Comment: @salvationishere I know you're not new here, but if you have tried things you should share your code, explain what didn't work or how it didn't do what you wanted/expected. If the duplicate doesn't get you where you need, post a new question, but first see [ask], and provide a [mcve].

Comment: This may be a dupe, but simple enough to represent as a oneliner: `Get-ADGroupMember GroupName | Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress | Select Name, SamAccountName, EmailAddress | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Path\To\file.csv`

Comment: Thank you, Bender.  The problem I had though was that I need all Names and email addresses for my Local Windows Groups (not AD groups).  Do you know how to do this?